# Detecting circle intersection from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas

I have a canvas on which I can place circles wherever I click. I want to detect when any two circle intersect, so i am storing my coordinates in an array.

The radius of every circle is 30, so that is just hardcoded into my formula. That said, even when I place two on top of each other, it's not triggering my little filltext to let me know that it's working. I've tried many things. If someone could tell me why this isn't working, that would be appreciable. The parts where I place the dots works just fine; I just need to detect overlap.

```
window.onload = init;

function init() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("testCanvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var newPath = false;

    var circles = [];
    canvas.onmousedown = function(e) {
        newPath = true;

        x = e.clientX - e.target.offsetLeft;
        y = e.clientY - e.target.offsetTop;
        context.moveTo(x, y);

        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(x, y, 30, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
        var nextColor = randomColor();
        context.fillStyle = nextColor; 
        context.fill();
        var aCircle = [x, y];

        function isIntersect(aCircle, circle) {
            return Math.sqrt((aCircle[0]-circle.x) ** 2 + (aCircle[1] - circle.y) ** 2) < 30;
          };

        circles.forEach(circle => {
            if (isIntersect(aCircle, circle)) {
                context.fillText('INTERSECTED', 60, 160);
            }
        });

        circles.push(aCircle);

        context.closePath(); 


    }
}
```

Comment: `aCircle` is using array indexing, but `circle` is using `x` and `y` properties. The circles you are generating should use array indexing (line 21).

Comment: Also, I believe that the intersection condition should be `<= 30`. If the circles are exactly 30 apart, they would intersect at a single point.

Comment: I can't believe it was something so small. I've been overlooking that for hours. Thank you, and yes regarding the 30. good idea.

Comment: Hint: don't look for hours at code. Just use the debugger to inspect every value you use, and you'd have found an `undefined` out there.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply the radius by 2 since each circle has one...

```js
window.onload = init;

function init() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("testCanvas");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var newPath = false;

  var circles = [];
  canvas.onmousedown = function(e) {
    newPath = true;

    x = e.clientX - e.target.offsetLeft;
    y = e.clientY - e.target.offsetTop;
    context.moveTo(x, y);

    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(x, y, 30, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
    var nextColor = '#123123' //randomColor();
    context.fillStyle = nextColor;
    context.fill();
    var aCircle = [x, y];

    function isIntersect(aCircle, circle) {
      var radius = 30;
      var dist = Math.hypot(aCircle[0]-circle[0], aCircle[1]-circle[1]);
      return dist <= (radius * 2)
    };

    circles.forEach(circle => {
      if (isIntersect(aCircle, circle)) {
        console.log("intresected");
        //context.fillText('INTERSECTED', 0, 0);
      }
    });

    circles.push(aCircle);

    context.closePath();


  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id='testCanvas'></canvas>
```